# Drive shows Nothing but full

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, virus

My External Hard drive have been infected with virus. the thing is its supposed to be 500GB but it shows it only have 2.56gb left out of 465GB. Now I have showed hidden files and found the black folder where the virus is supposed to hide your files but when i open it its empty and nothing else is on the drive but the virus itself the shortcut files and the autorun files. i cannot see my files even in recycler i cant see it. anyone got any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason definitely is **[Shortcut Virus](http://www.en.usbfix.net/2014/03/remove-shortcut-virus-usb/)** it hides your files by changing them as a system file. and windows does not show the system files by default.

to view your files you can remove `system` attribute or make windows show system files.
to unsystem files do:

Open `cmd.exe` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Or type cmd in start menu).
then type these lines in Command Prompt:

`attrib -s -h -r /S /D "driveLetter"` (put your HDD drive letter instead of `driveLetter`)

And to make windows show system file go to: `Control Panel > Folder Option > View[tab]` then find `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` and uncheck it. then press `OK`.

But i suggest you to clean your system by a Shortcut Virus Removal tool (like [UsbFix](http://www.en.usbfix.net/download/usbfix/)) which will work definitely.

Comment: Open cmd.exe by pressing Ctrl+R and type cmd and press Enter (Or type cmd in start menu). then type these lines in Command Prompt:

attrib -s -h -r /S /D "driveLetter" (put your HDD drive letter instead of driveLetter) 
=====
if this means the same as going to Tools> Folder Options > view of explorer and clicking show hidden files and unchecking the first 3 boxes below it is the same, i guess im already done with that.

if not just in case i have tried that also it says cant find "driveletter"

Comment: FYI these are the commands i typed in exactly:

attrib -s -h -r /S /D "i:\"
attrib -s -h -r /S /D "i"

for I as my drive letter

Comment: use the command like this: `attrib -s -h -r /S /D i:`. did u tried UsbFix?

Comment: Yes ive tried the usbfix it didnt do anything but add a folder to my usb named autorun.inf.

as for the command still the same. heres an image for your reference 

http://s27.postimg.org/5so5tlhj7/Virus.jpg
http://s21.postimg.org/cdeiehc87/CMD.jpg

Comment: O_o Actually it's a kinda weird says: `File Not Found`. cause it's a Path not file (mine says: `Path not found` when i tested it on an absent partition) are you sure that your HDD is connected to PC and u r using Administrator account when you run the command? even when the command runs finally it's not a final and continual way to see your files. because your system is infected and the virus can re-hidden files again(Shortcut Virus makes your file hidden all in an untitled folder to make itself visible as a shortcut and fool you to run it). so definitely use UsbFix. it'll certainly works.

Comment: What UsbFix exactly does when u run it? (you have to click on Deletion and wait to restart, then it'll scan ALL YOUR CONNECTED DISK DRIVES. so make sure your HDD is connected when scanning and it's turned on). tell me if something weird occured or it didn't work.(with error message) hope i can help u :)

Comment: yes it scans all drive and my drive is still connected as you can see in the image i have attached earlier its still there. it just scans for virus then nothing my drive still say 2.6gb out of 465gb. FYI I know how to show hidden files, and there is really nothing else here. I really dont wanna format it yet since i need my files inside. ive tried using recuva but the files i get are the old files ive deleted. not the files that are supposedly there currently.

Comment: No, do not format your HDD. cause it doesn't infected your files. it just moved them all to an untitled folder which is hidden by the virus. If you see your files there, make a backup of them and then clean your system or format infected HDD or sth. If not i've a short [program](https://www.mediafire.com/?jyf7twbflnj4d0a) which i used to make files hidden by Shortcut Virus visible. download and copy that into your HDD root folder and run it. then choose 2 and press `Enter`. then you can backup ur files. hope it works!

Comment: hi @Sdghasemi iended up reformating it. its really not in there. the untitled drive is empty. thanks you helped alot too

Comment: @gboy Your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Boot up a clean install (or better, if you have the knowledge, a Linux disk), and start pulling out your important data to another disk, then reinstall.

It sounds like you can't trust the OS, so you need to break out of the garden its put you in to fix the problem.

Comment: My System is fresh install, i tried booting it up on my linux server aswell still the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kaspersky Rescue Disk.
You can get from this [link](http://support.kaspersky.co.uk/4162)
Once Kaspersky Rescue Disk is downloaded, record it to a CD / DVD or any USB device and then start your computer from it. then scan your external hard drive with it.

Comment: I have tried and scanned it with rescue disk, it had found many virus. but still wont show my files. ive browsed it using file manager in rescue disc, and the only file that i can say mine is the movies folder which is inside system volume information. i have checked every folder in system vol but all it has are change.log  and restorepointsize